# Vue 3 Pinia - Fetched value from API in Pinia store can not be assigned as constant, always reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a **vue3 frontend** set up **with pinia as store**, like this:

```
  export const useShopStore = defineStore(
  "shop",
  () => {
    const state = reactive({
      data: {
        fruits: [],
        owners: [],
      },
    });

    let data_copy = {
      fruits: [],
      owners: [],
    };

    async function fetchData() {
      const URL = `${API_URL}/shops`;

      await axios
        .get(URL)
        .then((res) => {
          state.data = { ...res.data };
          data_copy = { ...res.data };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response) {
            console.log(err.response);
          }
        });
    }

    return { data, data_copy, fetchData };
 },
  {
    persist: true,
  }
);
```

**PROBLEM:**
NO matter what i tried, the variable data_copy is always a reactive copy of data.state.

**GOAL:**
What i want to achieve is that i fetch the data and assign it
a.) to the reactive variable state.data as well as
b.) to the NON-reactive variable data_copy

**REASON:**
In the template, i have a checkbox group and a computed property to compare the arrays in state.data with the data object that was originally fetch, data_copy. If the state.data object changed, a button "Update changes" is enabled.
Meaning, after fetching the data from the API and assigning the result to data_copy, data_copy should never change.

I also tried `Object.assign({}, res.data)` instead of the deconstruction syntax, that also did not work.

**QUESTION:**
How can i get a truly constant copy from the fetchData result independent of state.data?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i tried the following which works:

```
async function fetchData() {
  const URL = `${API_URL}/shops`;

  await axios
    .get(URL)
    .then((res) => {
      state.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));
      data_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response);
      }
    });
}
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759901).

Comment: `JSON` is the most simplistic and inefficient way to clone an object. Also, you don't need to clone it twice, since res.data isn't used anywhere else

Comment: `const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data))
state.data = data;
data_copy = data;`this does not work. @EstusFlask how would you suggest to do it cloning only once?

Comment: I mean `data_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data)); state.data = res.data`